# Viewpager fragments with gridview

Tags: android

What is the correct way to create fragments with gridview?
Can I do it like this?

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

And how do I add adapter to the gridview in runtime to add items to it?

```
private void initialisePaging() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, fragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, fragment2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, fragment3.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //this.mPagerAdapter.setListener(this);
    Log.e("init", "message");
    pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_menu);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.layout.menu1_fragment);
}
```

When I do that, the gridview is null and I cannot attach adapter to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find/configure views on individual pages in the `instantiateItem` method of your `PagerAdapter`, not when you're configuring the pager itself. Each page is created lazily when it's needed, and `instantiateItem` is what's called for each page to set it up. At the point where you're trying to find your `GridView` instance here, it doesn't exist yet because the pager hasn't created it, and you haven't localized it to which page you want to set up.

Comment: And how exactly do I get the gridView?   
  @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  Fragment g = fragments.get(position);
  GridView gridView = (GridView) g.getView();
 
  return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
 }
GridView is still null.